# Using participles in a row

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

> Retrospective cross-sectional study of type 2 diabetes patients
>   ***admitted*** to the geriatric ward ***receiving*** diabetes medications. (Original)

Is using participles as in the example above grammatically correct? + Is any of the sentences below superior to the original one?

> 2- Retrospective cross-sectional study of type 2 diabetes patients
>   ***admitted*** to the geriatric ward ***,*** ***receiving*** diabetes medications.
>
> 3- Retrospective cross-sectional study of type 2 diabetes patients
>   ***admitted*** to the geriatric ward ***and*** ***receiving*** diabetes
>   medications.

Answer (score 1):

1) and 2) are not different in meaning.  The comma would certainly be necessary in most contexts (but somehow seems awkward in a title or paper abstract?)

1) and 3) are close in meaning.   3) is preferable because there is an ambiguity:

```
 admitted to the geriatric ward receiving diabetes medication
```

Does it mean that the patient was admitted to the hospital, and is currently receiving medication?

Or does it mean that the patient was receiving medication at the time they were admitted to the hospital?

Although 1) is not incorrect usage, because of this ambiguity, you should prefer to use 3) if you mean the first thing, especially in this sort of technical and formal writing.

If you mean the second thing:

```
admitted to the geriatric ward while receiving diabetes medication
```

Comment: I believe the distinction between (1) and (2) was the addition of a comma before "receiving"

Comment: Ah, my eyesight is horrible.   Missed that.